# HTML5 Canvas merging to rectangles to form a new shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a page that you will be able to draw squares on it. The squares will represent a room, so you have one square, then you make another over the first square and then two will join

It will looks like this
http://puu.sh/bllo7/95e2112d79.png

And functions like so http://jsfiddle.net/bLenxexL/

I need to figure out how get them squares to make another shape that will look like the image on the right of the picture above.

If this helps, the square info is stored in `points` in this format

```
[
    {
        start: {x: 312, y: 164}, 
        end: {x: 734, y: 371}
    },
    {
        start: {x: 696, y: 304}, 
        end: {x: 1060, y: 561}
    }
]
```

Any links to resources that will help me do this will be of  much help thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use compositing to create a single stroke around your combined rectangles.

- draw all your rectangles with strokes
- set compositing to 'destination-out'.  This causes new drawings to "erase" existing drawings where the two overlap.
- fill all your rects.  This erases all but the outline of the combined rectangles.

This works because strokes are drawn half-inside & half-outside the border of rectangles. When you erase the inside of the combined rectangles you are left with the half-outside strokes.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/m5jg92wd/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw all rects with strokes
    ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,200);
    ctx.strokeRect(90,110,75,50);

    // set compositing to erase existing drawings 
    // new drawings will erase existing drawings where the two overlap
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';

    // fill all rects
    // This "erases" all but the outline stroke
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,200);
    ctx.fillRect(90,110,75,50);

    // reset compositing to its default mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```