# Merging two shapes inside html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing a freehand drawing webapp using the HTML Canvas element. So far, I can draw shapes onto the sceeen that look like the following images.

I have stored all the points of the shapes into a JS array. For instance:

```
[
 [
  [118, 171],
  [118, 170],
  [118, 167],
  ...
 ],
 [
  [236, 131],
  [236, 133],
  [236, 135],
  ...
 ]
]
```

I'm now looking for a way to merge certain shapes, imagine that I would like to merge the two shapes in the following picture, here's how it would look like.

I think I have to redraw to the canvas but filter out all the points that are inside another shape.

The first idea that I had was to find a solution to check if a specific point was contained inside another shape and if it's the case, skip it. However, that would probably not work since `moveTo`/`lineTo`/`stroke` would create a line between the last independant point before a shape and the first independant after a shape.

I've looked up [compositing operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing) that might be able to help, but haven't found a way to implement it yet.

How could I approach this feature ?

**Input**

[image: Input]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Canvas merging to rectangles to form a new shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670455/html5-canvas-merging-to-rectangles-to-form-a-new-shape)

Comment: This isn't only rectangles though

Comment: `MoveTo` won't create a line

Comment: Draw on colored background, shapes single solid color without border - merged parts should not make border

Comment: @Justinas I'm not sure to understand your answer, since the shapes are "hand-drawn", how would you not create a border ? The coordinates that I'm referring to are the different points that form the border/the edges of the shape

Comment: @ThéoLavaux Shapes then has only fill color - even line is shape of 1px width

Comment: What if I want to keep "empty" shapes with a black border and white inside?

Answer (score 3):

The following code is not a complete solution. It uses Path2D objects (still marked as an "experimental technology" by MDN) and the isPointInPath() canvas function.

```js
// Canvas boilerplate
const canvas = document.querySelector('#mycanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create our shapes
const shape1 = [[100, 100], [70, 200], [150, 250], [300, 250], [300, 100], [150, 50]];
const shape2 = [[60, 60], [60, 160], [110, 210], [260, 210], [260, 60], [110, 10]];

// Create Path2D objects from our shapes
let p1 = new Path2D();
p1.moveTo(...shape1[0]);
for (let i = 1; i < shape1.length; i++) {
  p1.lineTo(...shape1[i]);
}
p1.closePath();

let p2 = new Path2D();
p2.moveTo(...shape2[0]);
for (let i = 1; i < shape2.length; i++) {
  p2.lineTo(...shape2[i]);
}
p2.closePath();

// Draw the shapes onb the canvas
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.stroke(p1);

ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke(p2);

// Just for this demo, fill the shapes to make them look joined together
ctx.fill(p2);
ctx.fill(p1);

// Discover whether coordinate points are inside/outside the other shape
let inside = [],
    outside = [];

for (let i = 0; i < shape2.length; i++) {
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(p1, ...shape2[i])) inside.push(shape2[i]);
  else outside.push(shape2[i]);
}

for (let i = 0; i < shape1.length; i++) {
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(p2, ...shape1[i])) inside.push(shape1[i]);
  else outside.push(shape1[i]);
}

// Display coordinates inside
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
for (let i = 0; i < inside.length; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(...inside[i]);
  ctx.arc(...inside[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

// ... and outside
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
for (let i = 0; i < outside.length; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(...outside[i]);
  ctx.arc(...outside[i], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

To calculate a third shape which combines the coordinates of a path outlining the merged shape you need to work out which lines in each shape intersect, and where, then combine those new coordinates with your existing outside coordinates in the right order. Best of luck!

Comment: The shape is not necessarily a circle though,but thanks for sharing your reflexions!

Comment: Neither of the shapes above are circles - but you're welcome!